# why is react not re rendering on state change?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, state, setstate

Cant work out what is going wrong.
I click a button, this sets the state and the setting of state, changes a key to be true and if that key is true, a different output should be rendered. here is the code:

click button call function:

```
<input type="submit" value="I can play" onClick={() => this.canPlay()}/>
```

runs this function:

```
 canPlay: function() {
    let name = this.props.value;
    console.log(name, 'name');
    let email = 'mark@mail';
    this.submitUserResponseCanPlay(this.today(), name, email)
    this.setState({thanks: true}) //SET STATE HERE
  },
```

(thanks is set to false in getInitialState)

then in the render function:

```
render: function(){
    let output;
    if (this.state.thanks){
      output = <Thanks />;
    }
```

if the state is true, then render the new output. the ` part is a class that just has a return part inside the render function that looks like:

```
var Thanks = React.createClass({

  render: function(){
    return (
      <div id="results" className="search-results">
        Thanks, your answer has been recorded!
      </div>
    )
  }

});
```

This does not show up though. any idea why??

the stranger thing is it is like this in another part of my file, and that part works. i.e. i click a submit button earlier and that changes a key/value pair from false to true and renders a new page layout. just not working here. maybe ive missed something small..

Comment: I thunk you forgot the return() inside of the render() method

Comment: can you post the whole component rather than splitting it up into parts? it's possible you haven't bound canPlay

Comment: the component is pretty big. but what else do you want to see? there are two components

Comment: @Borjante i just left it out so not to include lots of code

Comment: It's just a hint, but for me, it's usually a rogue `shouldComponentUpdate` with a missing state comparison that causes this behavior.

Comment: @JohnWhite i do not have that method in my code as of yet

Comment: the problem is we cannot see how you are using the `output` variable in your render. we need to see the whole render function.

Comment: can you show the other working input and its function, it might be as simple as passing the event into the canPlay function so you can `event.preventDefault()` and `return false`

Answer (score 0):

```
render: function(){
let output;
if (this.state.thanks){
  output = <Thanks />;
}
```

This should be

```
render: function(){
if (this.state.thanks){
  return <Thanks />
}
```

You always have to return something inside the `render`

Comment: I do have something inside the render, I just missed it out to not show loads of code.

Comment: What I meant is that you need the `return` keyword

Comment: you dont have the whole context of the render function. it could be that output is used as a component later or something. we need to see more information

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can set variables as jsx so if im wrong ignore this. BUT in this case it seems like youre probably trying to render a

```
 {output}
```

somewhere in your code. instead replace that with

```
{this.state.thank ? <Thanks /> : null}
```